# Reading in rails parameters to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the parameters below being sent from a `<%= form_for(bid) do |f| %>` in a form to create a new bid.

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"kb1enToURu/KEIw4DbBKnuLScDjhkli1cwA==",
  "bid"=>{"amount"=>"34", "item_id"=>"5877e25a31d77f202480a5a9", "person_id"=>"58718f3431d77f288b9be837"},
  "commit"=>"Create Bid"
}
```

The create controller receives the request:

```
def create
  @bid = Bid.new(params[bid]) #need help here to create new bid
  render :index
end
```

The current create method gives me an "undefined local variable or method `bid' for #BidsController..."

How do I change the create method in the controller to read in the parameters and save the bid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `params[bid]` to `params[:bid]`

Comment: Arghrhrhg, too much Python today. Thank you :)